KeyCloak Container Refused or Reset Connection from Kong Container on the Same WSL2 Ubuntu Host
I am doing the tutorial in callistaenterprise/blog-api-gateway-kong: Sample project demonstrating Kong API Gateway usage. It works fine on MacOS. However I ran into troubles with the same docker-compose set up on WSL2 Ubuntu.
The keycloak container was set up with:
keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
    ports:
      - "9080:9080"
      - "9443:9443"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: 
      - start-dev
      - --db=dev-mem
      - --hostname=host.docker.internal
      - --http-port=9080
      - --https-port=9443
      - --https-certificate-file=/opt/keycloak/ssl/server/localhost.crt
      - --https-certificate-key-file=/opt/keycloak/ssl/server/localhost.key
      - --https-trust-store-file=/opt/keycloak/ssl/CA/localCA.p12
      - --https-trust-store-password=secret
      - --https-client-auth=request
      - --import-realm
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak-test-realm.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm.json
      - ./certs:/opt/keycloak/ssl

and the kong container access the keycloak with:
- name: oidc
  host:  upstream
  port: 80
  protocol: http
  plugins: 
  - name: oidc
    config: 
      discovery: http://host.docker.internal:9080/realms/test/.well-known/openid-configuration
      client_id: oidc-client
      client_secret: secret
  routes:
  - name: oidc-route
    paths:
    - /oidc/
    strip_path: true

The tutorial adds a 127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal entry into /etc/hosts

With WSL 2 on Windows 10, the hosts file has an entry like 10.171.xxx.xxx host.docker.internal, which is not accessible and was likely put there by Docker Desktop for Windows 10, so I put generateHosts = false in the /etc/wsl.conf file to make the IP address of host.docker.internal be 127.0.0.1

The problem is that when I do http http://host.docker.internal:8080/oidc/api, it in turn makes a request to http://host.docker.internal:9080/realms/test/.well-known/openid-configuration and returns the error of connection refused.

If adding a network_mode: host option in the kong container, http http://host.docker.internal:8080/oidc/api returns the error of connection reset by peer.

If keycloak container also has the network_mode: host, the error would again be connection refused



However in both case, http http://host.docker.internal:9080/realms/test/.well-known/openid-configuration works fine.
It seems a Windows/WSL/Docker network set up issue. Can anyone shed some light onto it?

Experimented different setups and managed to get it working.

First it is likely the Windows/WSL environment causes the hassle. Be default, Windows firewall blocks by default WSL environment to access the host. The entry host.docker.internal in Windows's hosts file is always the Windows host but could not be accessed by the WSL.

The corporate IT does not allow individual to change the Windows firewall setting. It would be a bureaucratic nightmare to ask an exception. Give up.


So I have to stick with host.docker.internal being set to 127.0.0.1 and set generateHosts = false with the /etc/wsl.conf file. The only configuration that works is:

Both kong and keycloak container have to set the network mode to be host
Both containers have to add a volume mapping /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts
Without the above two changes, changing oidc service's discovery URL to http://keycloak:9080/realms/test/.well-known/openid-configuration can get the inter-docker access work, but it stops short as the last step is a HTTP redirect to http://keycloak:9080/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/auth, but the host cannot resolve keycloak

However host can ping the IP address of keycloak





